# Using For Loop in Liquid to build accordion FAQ

Tags: shopify, liquid, sections

I am pretty new to Liquid and coding in general. I found a tutorial that helped me build a custom section for my Shopify page that allows me to add questions and answers to a FAQ page.

My goal is to have different categories of questions. Using the following code, when clicking on a question (tab) in an instance other than the original, it opens the tab in the original section rather than the particular section that I am editing.

```
<div class="grid-item-100">
<div class="faq">
{%for block in section.blocks%}
  <div class="tab">
        <input type="checkbox" id="tab{{forloop.index}}" class="tab-toggle">
    <label for="tab{{forloop.index}}" class="tab-label">{{block.settings.question}}</label>
        <div class="tab-content">{{block.settings.answer}}</div>
  </div>
  {%endfor%}
```

I know that this is because of the forloop being used for the tab id's, I just don't know how to rewrite this for it to work specifically on the instance of the section that I want.

Here is the rest of the schema as well:

```
    {% schema %}
  {
    "name": "FAQ-SECTION-2",
    "settings": [],
    "blocks" : [
        {
            "type":"text",
            "name":"Question/Answer",
            "settings":[
                {
                    "id":"question",
                    "type":"text",
                    "label":"the question"
                },
                {
                    "id":"answer",
                    "type":"richtext",
                    "label":"answer"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

[Here is an image to help visualize the issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ZVV.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following this tutorial: https://easycodeguide.com/build-customizable-faqs-page-using-section-shopify.html

It allows for separators within it and then has separate cases for either it is looping through a separator or Q/A.